# Getting Error of Modification of a read-only value attempted

Tags: perl

I am trying to select the below value from database:

> Reporting that one of @its many problems had been the recent@ extended
>   sales slump in women's apparel, the seven-store retailer said it would
>   start a three-month liquidation sale in all of its stores.~(A) its
>   many problems had been the recent~(B) its many problems has been the
>   recently~(C) its many problems is the recently~(D) their many problems
>   is the recent~(E) their many problems had been the recent~

i am selecting this value in variable $ques and then selecting a text as below:

```
$ques=~s/^(.*?)\@(.*?)\@(.*?)$/$2/;
```

Now, while replacing the ~ character in the string by

```
$3=~s/~/\n/g;    ---->line 171
```

and running the script, I am getting one error as:

```
Modification of a read-only value attempted at main.pl line 171
```

I want to replace all the ~ character with '\n' and print the final value. Please suggest how to do it.

*I have researched this on net, but got confused that how to handle these read only variables.

Comment: I think You directly cant modify $3 assgn it a variable and then do the substitution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you really want in this case is [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) rather than regular expression capture groups:

```
my @parts = split(/@/, $ques);
$parts[2] =~ s/~/\n/g;
```

It makes the intent of your code clearer since you are, in fact, splitting on `@` symbols.

Comment: Thanks, My approach was wrong. Using this, i am getting the desired result!

Answer (score 3):

You've already got a good explanation of the problem from José Castro. But there's another solution if you're using a recent-ish version of Perl (**Update:** having checked more carefully, I find that means 5.14+). The `/r` argument to the substitution operator will copy your string, make the substitution on the copy and then return that altered value.

So you could write:

```
my $new_value = $3 =~ s/~/\n/rg;
```

Comment: I am using Perl 5.10. And it seems this is giving a syntax error while implementing.

Comment: Yes. As I said, this feature was added in Perl 5.14. Why don't you use a version of Perl that was released this decade? :-)

Comment: I am working on something for my personal use but in office system. So I cannot upgrade it untill and unless I have a manager's approval. :P

Comment: Well, firstly, why is your office using such an old version of Perl? And, secondly, you don' need to upgrade the system Perl - use perlbrew to install a newer version of Perl alongside the existing one.

Answer (score 2):

Just like you say, the special variables `$1`, `$2`, etc., are read-only, and that means that you can't perform that substitution on them.

Performing the substitution on `$ques` will do what you need:

```
$ques =~ s/~/\n/g;
print $ques;
```

Do note that in the earlier substitution that you're performing on `$ques` you're getting rid of all the `~` characters.

Comment: Hi, Actually I am printing the output as below:
`print "$1", colored("$ques",'underline','yellow'),"$party","\n";`
And it is printing the complete text in underline if I replace ~ with \n before splitting it.